# AWS batch inside step function passing output to next state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I am new to both aws step function and aws batch job. I have a project where I have a batch job as first state in the state machine. I am trying to figure out how the output of this first batch job (first stage in step function) will be passed to the next state in the state machine. e.g. the batch job in the state machine performs addition of two numbers and I need to pass the addition to the next step.

I have found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-batch.html) link to invoke a batch job inside step function but it does not tell anything about passing the output to next state.

Also I have explored [callback option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token) but as per my understanding, it requires batch job to be outside of the step function. My understanding is, something like lambda (inside step function) will submit the batch job(out of step function) with token and step function will wait for token to be returned with result.

Can someone help to figure this out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it. You can checkout the solution in this post  [AWS Batch Job Execution Results in Step Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851932/2246345).

The key was in the `Submit Job Output` which contained the `LogStreamName`.